# CSS3/HTML animate position:fixed div onto page

Tags: html, css

I have a little pseudo modal I am building for my app that takes over the screen for a moment when a user clicks the button. I have it set as position fixed so it can overtake the entire screen infront of the user. I have it show and hiding right now with just toggling between `display: block` and `display: none`, my css right now just looks like so :

(SCSS) :

```
 .sort-fullscreen {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: $modal-bg-color;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    transition: all 0.5;

    &.open {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

And there is just a

```
<div class="sort-fullscreen">
  ... users content
</div>
```

Sitting at the bottom of my page.

So this works fine, however I am trying to figure out if there is a way to animate the position fixed coming onto the page - perhaps sliding on and off?

Initially - I tried something like this

```
.sort-fullscreen {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: $modal-bg-color;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    transition: all 0.5;

    &.open {
       left: 0%;
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work for me. I cannot seem to find a clean way to animate a position fixed onto the page. Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seemed to work for me, albeit after adding 's' in your transition time:

```
transition: all 0.5s;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dt2j6872/1/